# Preview Version 8.0 (859.21) How to extract images from PDF

Tags: pdf

I have found that there was an option to extract images from PDFs via "Save to iPhoto" option of Preview.

Unfortunately, I don't see this option in Version 8.0 (859.21).

Is there still an option to export images from this Version of Preview? Any other ways native to Yosemite?

scrshot of Preview Print Options

[image]

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`File` > `Export...` can save any Preview-compatible file in any other Preview-compatible file format. Save your PDF as a picture file, such as JPEG or PNG, and then open that file and crop it until it's just the image you want.